# Multiple condition is JSON assertion in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

For my http request call I am getting following JSON response,

```
{
    "id": "29133",
    "status": {
        "overall": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "subStatus": "BATCH_GENERATION_STARTED",
        "failureDetails": null,
        "statusHistory": [
            {
                "overall": "OPENED",
                "subStatus": null,
                "startTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:39.2391116",
                "endTimestamp": null
            },
            {
                "overall": "UPLOAD_COMPLETE",
                "subStatus": null,
                "startTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:39.2391116",
                "endTimestamp": null
            },
            {
                "overall": "IN_PROGRESS",
                "subStatus": "CSV_VALIDATION_STARTED",
                "startTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:39.2391116",
                "endTimestamp": null
            },
            {
                "overall": "IN_PROGRESS",
                "subStatus": "CSV_VALIDATION_COMPLETE",
                "startTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:39.2391116",
                "endTimestamp": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "initiatedBy": "bulk_admin_user",
    "product": "TEST",
    "entity": "STE",
    "operation": "ADDJ_JOB",
    "startTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:39.2391116",
    "endTimestamp": null,
    "file": {
        "totalRecords": 0,
        "totalFailedRecords": 0,
        "totalSuccessRecords": 0,
        "totalInProgressRecords": 0,
        "numBatches": 0,
        "maxBatchSize": 1000,
        "batches": []
    },
    "results": {
        "successFileAvailable": false,
        "failureFileAvailable": false
    },
    "actionsAvailable": {
        "dataUploadAllowed": false,
        "abortJob": false,
        "restartJob": false,
        "actionHistory": [
            {
                "initatedTimestamp": "2021-05-24T06:54:41.9525781",
                "actionType": "UPLOAD_COMPLETE",
                "initiatedBy": "bulk_admin_user"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the status section I want to validate the `overall` section, there are two values I am expecting `"IN_PROGRESS" and "UPLOAD_COMPLETE"`.

I want to validate using JSON assertion in JMeter and I have used the following,
[image]

Somehow the above condition is not working, what I have missed here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why you are `JSON` assertion, why not a JSR223 assertion using the following script,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    status = jsonResponse.status.overall            
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}
        if (status.contains('IN_PROGRESS') || status.contains('UPLOAD_COMPLETE')){
                AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
            }
            else {
                AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
                AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
            }
```

This will cover your ask ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your JSON Path expression to use [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) to catch all `status` attributes values

   ```
   $.status..overall
   ```
2. Your [regular expression](https://regex101.com/) is not very correct, if you expect the match to contain both `IN_PROGRESS` and `UPLOAD_COMPLETE` you should amend it to something like:

   ```
   .*IN_PROGRESS.*UPLOAD_COMPLETE.*
   ```

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Like this as well, crispy and small